# Is it possible to execute JavaScript within an AJAX response that gets generated in the server's PHP code?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xss

I want to output a time zone next to a date time value from PHP, only after the rows have been sent to the client.

I compose the time zone statements as such, but need to display them only on empty cell values.  I did not succeed with coalescing nulls to the empty string after the date time.   I want to display nothing if the cell is blank.

How do I execute the JS block in code after transmission to client, should I be placing the execution result in the client page JS?  Is this at all possible in the first place?   Note: timeouts did not help to delay execution.

**JS PHP Statement String**

```
<?php
            $jsTimeZoneStatements .="if ($('td#plug$idx span').text().trim() != '') $('span#timezonePlug$idx').html(getTimezoneName());if ($('td#unplug$idx span').text().trim() != '') $('span#timezoneUnplug$idx').html(getTimezoneName());";
            $idx++;
?>
```

**Script Under HTML Table that does not seem to run or execute immediately after client receives (this is via an AJAX call).**

```
<script>
    var script = "<?php echo "<code>(()=>{$jsTimeZoneStatements})();</code>"?>";
    $('#deviceHistoryScript').append(script);
</script>
```

**Unrolled (What AJAX gets from server)**

```
"...(stuff above this is HTML content)...<div id=\"#deviceHistoryScript\">

    

</div>

<script>

    var script = \"<code>(()=>if ($('td#plug0 span').text().trim() != '') $('span#timezonePlug0').html(getTimezoneName());if ($('td#unplug0 span').text().trim() != '') $('span#timezoneUnplug0').html(getTimezoneName());if ($('td#plug1 span').text().trim() != '') $('span#timezonePlug1').html(getTimezoneName());if ($('td#unplug1 span').text().trim() != '') $('span#timezoneUnplug1').html(getTimezoneName());if ($('td#plug2 span').text().trim() != '') $('span#timezonePlug2').html(getTimezoneName());if ($('td#unplug2 span').text().trim() != '') $('span#timezoneUnplug2').html(getTimezoneName());)();</code>\";

    $('#deviceHistoryScript').append(script);

</script>"
```

Comment: Am I allowed to execute JS once AJAX receives content?  This is probably the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to execute the code received from the ajax request? Like this https://subinsb.com/how-to-execute-javascript-in-ajax-response/

Comment: it looks like you're using jQuery. Methods like `.html()` will execute scripts.

Comment: @Barmar, Did not know that...

Comment: try without these complex calculations to make statically one of the options for which script should be executed. after it works correctly, redo it for dynamic shaping.

Comment: @romanown  did you mistakenly answer a different question??

Comment: wrapping the Script under html table js code, with a document.ready(()=>{}); allowed the script to execute on th client

Comment: I wrote to You. to check why it doesn't work, first make one of the possible script options. delete all calculations and write it down as it should be in the final form. after you make it workable, you will add calculations for dynamic script generation. this way you will find the reason why each stage doesn't work.

Comment: why to use <code>? show html with this selectors. to try simply. after run is go next. <script>
    var script = \"<code>(()=>$('span#timezonePlug0').html('name');$('span#timezoneUnplug0').html('name1'); $('span#timezonePlug1').html('name2');$('span#timezoneUnplug1').html('name3'); $('span#timezonePlug2').html('name4');$('span#timezoneUnplug2').html('name5');)();</code>\";
    $('#deviceHistoryScript').append(script);
</script>

Comment: to try on this codepen https://codepen.io/romanown/pen/VwKPaay  when simplified, you can see that the script is not executed. only its contents are shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225874/discussion-between-vahe-jabagchourian-and-romanown).

Comment: i writed to discuss

Comment: Thank you, romanown,  I have reached a conclusion provided the necessary adjustments